# SyndicationItem.Content is Null

Tags: c#, rss, syndication-feed, syndication-item

I'm trying to pull the contents of an RSS feed into an object that can be manipulated in code. It looks like the SyndicationFeed and SyndicationItem classes in .NET 3.5 will do what I need, except for one thing. Every time I've tried to read in the contents of an RSS feed using the SyndicationFeed class, the .Content element for each SyndicationItem is null.

I've run my feed through FeedValidator and have tried this with feeds from several other sources, but to no avail.

```
XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create("http://shortordercode.com/feed/");
SyndicationFeed feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(xr);

foreach (SyndicationItem item in feed.Items)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Title.Text);
    Console.WriteLine(item.Content.ToString());
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

I suspect I may just be missing a step somewhere, but I can't seem to find a good tutorial on how to consume RSS feeds using these classes.

EDIT: Thanks to SLaks I've figured out that the issue is with WordPress's use of  as the content tag. This doesn't appear to be a problem with the WP Atom feeds so I'll go with that as a solution for now. Thanks SLaks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This should get content for you:

```
SyndicationFeed feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);

string content = feed.ElementExtensions.ReadElementExtensions<string>("encoded", "http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/")
```

Comment: Thanks Francis. I just came across this solution on another SO post and it did indeed give me what I needed. Actually it helped solve two or three other niggling issues as well!

Answer (score 6):

Its due to the fact that it is content:encoded instead of content. To read the content in this case, I am going to use this:

```
    string content="";
    foreach (SyndicationElementExtension ext in item.ElementExtensions)
    {
        if (ext.GetObject<XElement>().Name.LocalName == "encoded")
            content = ext.GetObject<XElement>().Value;
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Take a look what I did:

```
    XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("http://kwead.com/blog/?feed=atom");
    SyndicationFeed feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);
    reader.Close();

    foreach (SyndicationItem item in feed.Items)
    {
        string data = item.PublishDate.ToString();
        DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(data);

        string titulo = " - " + item.Title.Text + "<br>";
        string conteudo = ((TextSyndicationContent)item.Content).Text;

        Response.Write(dt.ToString("d"));
        Response.Write(titulo);
        Response.Write(conteudo);
     }
```

Comment: This seems to work correctly for atom feeds, unfortunately the RSS spec allows for extensions, which is what the content:encoded thing is. It's valid, and that's what's preventing the item.content piece from working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Summary` property.

The RSS feed you linked to puts its content in the `<description>` element.
[As documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationitem.aspx), the `<description>` element of an RSS feed maps to the `Summary` property.

Comment: The summary property only provides a small amount of the content from the feed, does it not?

Comment: It provides the `<description>` element.

Comment: But I'm looking to get the full text of the articles/blog posts. Am I going about it wrong?

Comment: In looking at the feed, it's the `Content` element I'm looking to read.

Comment: Hmm.. will have to keep looking I guess. That's the way all WordPress feed's do the content tag.

Comment: @kdmurray - Did you find a way of getting the full blog posts from any feed irrespective of whether it's encoded or not?

Comment: @user102533 - The short answer is no -- at least not with the MS framework. I'm looking into some third party tools to make this work.

Comment: UPDATE: 9-Jan-2011: @Francis-Shanahan has provided a workaround using built-in .NET functions that is able to read the extensions properly.